# Windows API error 32

Tags: errors

I'm brand new to LaTeX; any idea how to overcome this error message?

```
"texify.exe: Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is
being used by another process.
texify.exe: Data: untitled-1.log"
```

Comment: Windows is unable to open a same file by 2 programs simultaneously. Either quit the program that owns untitler-1.log, or -- it's probably the best thing to do -- reboot your computer to clean the locks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the suggestion copied from my answer to your cross-post [Windows API Error 32](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=22638) in the [LaTeX-Community.org forum](http://latex-community.org/forum):

The error message says it: some process blocks the file, Windows cannot open it for that reason. For example, if you have the output file open in the Adobe Acrobat Reader, LaTeX cannot write on it because the reader blocks it, similarly having the .log file open in an editor may block it.

So you could do one of the following:

- Stop compilation, if there's one running, and close viewer programs, specifically if you have the .log file open in an editor
- Use the Windows task manager to locate process which may use it and kill them (editor, viewer, texify, ...)
- Reboot your computer, which closes all programs and removes the file locks
- Use other programs which don't block files

The first solutions are quick, the third one is clean, the last one an option for the future.